# 303 Error while using xmlrpc in web2py for command line interface for a web application

Tags: python, xml-rpc, web2py

I have the following functions defined in test.py file

```
@auth.requires_login()
def call():
    return service()

@service.xmlrpc
def time():
    import time
    return time.ctime()
```

and following in my db.py file

```
auth.settings.allow_basic_login = True  #for CLI access
```

When I execute the following commands in python shell :

```
server = ServerProxy( 'https://username:password@10.20.254.39/cloud_computing/test/call/xmlrpc' )
server.time()
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1199, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1489, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1243, in request
    headers
xmlrpclib.ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for username:password@10.20.254.39/cloud_computing/test/call/xmlrpc: 303 SEE OTHER>
```

Am, I doing something wrong somewhere?

Comment: A 303 response isn't really an error: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4

Comment: But that doesn't make me reach any step closer to the solution of my problem. Does it?

Comment: well, I'm no expert in web2py but I do know that if a HTTP client treats a 303 as an error, there's a problem with that client. Maybe there's also a problem with the server, but a client should be able to process a 303 response.

Comment: Are you requesting this over http and getting redirected to https?

Comment: Try this with curl, and its `-L` option ... this will follow the `303` to its redirect link. Am suspecting the `303` is either to the regular login page or something else.

Comment: Additionally, does the service work, if you remove the authentication?